I am attempting leetcode problem #3 but running into time limit exceeded
I'm trying to solve LeetCode problem 3. Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters:

Given a string s, find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters.
Example 1:
Input: s = "abcabcbb"
Output: 3
Explanation: The answer is "abc", with the length of 3.

To this, I can only think of a brute force solution, where you find all the possible substrings, check if they are valid, and then find the max length of those substrings. This is what I have so far:
#returns true if there is a duplicate character
def count_characters(self,s):
    for i in s:
        if s.count(i)>1:
            return True
    return False

def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s):
    """
    :type s: str
    :rtype: int
    """
    #generate list of all substrings
    max_len = 0 

    for i in range(len(s)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(s)+1):
            substr = s[i:j]
            if len(substr)>max_len and not self.count_characters(substr):
                    max_len = len(substr)
            print(substr)

    return max_len

What should I do to pass the tests with longer inputs such that I don't hit a timeout?

You need to figure out a non-brute force solution. They deliberately use large test cases that will cause brute force to fail.

Try stepping through the input string a character at a time, constructing a substring as you go. For each character, check if it's already in the substring. When you get a repeat, save the substring you just created. Then start a new substring, which starts after the character this one duplicated in the previous substring.

Each time you get to the end of a substring, before saving it, check if it's longer than the existing saved substring.

you can check for duplicates by doing len(set(substr)) == len(substr), most of the code runs in C so it will be faster than any raw  loop you can ever write.

you can also break from the inner loop once you the condition tells you that you have a repeating character, adding more characters to that string is not going to remove the repeated character.

Your approach is not efficient. The two nested loops make that the expression s[i:j] is evaluated O(²) times, while that expression itself has O() time complexity, where  is the size of the slice. This leads to an overall complexity of O(³).
The thing is that even when you have found a substring that has duplicate characters, you will still create larger substrings that have that substring in it. This is a waste of effort. You could consider that if you have a good substring, you only need to check the character that you would append to that substring to see if the substring is still valid. You actually don't even need to create the substring. Tracking the start/end indices of it together with the set of characters in it, can be enough.
This problem can be solved with a time complexity of O().
Try to come up with an efficient algorithm with the above analysis in mind.
Here are some more hints in case you need them:

 sliding window


 index of last character occurrence, per character

And finally a spoiler implementation:

 class Solution:
     def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s: str) -> int:
         last_occurence = {}  # per character: last found index for it
         exclude = -1  # index before the current substring's start
         longest = 0
         for i, ch in enumerate(s):
             exclude = max(exclude, last_occurence.get(ch, -1))
             last_occurence[ch] = i
             longest = max(longest, i - exclude)
         return longest


spoiler is pretty cool.

yea fr i didn tknow this worked

You can follow the standard process for a sliding window solution:

Use a left and right pointer (indexes) to represent the current best answer ending at the right index.
Keep moving the right pointer up while the current window is valid, updating the answer with the answer for the current window each time. Stop when the right pointer reaches the end.
When the current window becomes invalid, keep moving the left pointer up until the current window becomes valid again. Go back to step 2.

This directly leads to a linear (O(N)) solution as follows.
class Solution:
    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s: str) -> int:
        curr = set()
        l = ans = 0
        for r, c in enumerate(s):
            while c in curr:
                curr.remove(s[l])
                l += 1
            curr.add(c)
            ans = max(ans, r - l + 1)
        return ans


The answer is bounded by the alphabet size, if your string contains only lowercase English letters then after 27 letters you would defiantly have repeating character.
So in inner loop it's enough to loop up to 26 letters, with total complexity of O(N * 26).
